# Searching dictionary keys using values that have been input by the user

Tags: python, python-3.x

for this program i am attempting to search for a key in a dictionary using an input from the user, in this case the dictionary 'options1'.

```
'''
set up the dictionary with the information
---------------------------
these are the options for the user to input
'''

options1 = dict = {'1' : "blah",
            '2' : "blah?",
            '3' : "blah"}

options2 = dict = {'1':"blah",
            '2':"blah"}

options3 = dict = {1:"blah?",
            '2':"blah!"}

'''
these are the replies to the users inputs
'''

replies = dict = {'zero':"blah",
           'one':"blah",
           'two':"blah",
           'three':"'backs away slowly'"}

user_input = False          #setting the variable to false as default

class Choice:
    if user_input == False:         #checks to see if the variable 'user_input' is False. 
        print(replies["zero"])      #will then print the starting text
        print("------------------------------------")           #seperate line for easier reading
        print("---" + options1["1"] + " _ 1")           #prints the options for the reader
        print("---" + options1["2"] + " _ 2")           #prints the options for the reader
        print("---" + options1["3"] + " _ 3")           #prints the options for the reader
        reply = input("*type one of the numbers shown above to reply* ") #allows the user to input a number that reprisents an argument that they want to pass  

        if reply in dict.keys():    #checks to see if the number input by teh user is in the options1 dictionary.
            print('true')
        else:
            print('false')
```

here I'm using the variable 'reply' to check if the string is the same as a key in the options1 dictionary. for example the string '2' would be the same as the options1('2') key.

I expected the code to print the text true to show that it can find the key but instead prints false to show that it can't find the key.

```
if reply in dict.keys():    #checks to see if the number input by teh user is in the options1 dictionary.
    print('true')
else:
    print('false')
```

not sure why it does this. i have tried using 'options1[reply] in dict.keys()' nut would give me an error of "TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable"

any help would be appreciated.

(also for clarification this program is suppose to give the user conversation options that they can choose to reply to the given dialogue)

Comment: Why do you repeatedly use this type of assignment: `options2 = dict =`?

Comment: don't use `dict` as a variable as it's the dict class. And don't do `in dict.keys()`; do `in d` (no .keys())

Comment: Get rid of `= dict =` throughout the code and just have `options1 = {'1' : "blah", '2' : "blah?", '3' : "blah"}` etc throughout. The syntax makes it a dictionary, not `= dict`

Comment: your code doesn't help to show the issue. Please create a [mcve] that everyone can copy/paste in his/her favourite interpreter.

Comment: for example those lines reproduce your problem: `class D:
    pass
dict=D()
dict.keys = {}
dict.keys()
`

Comment: What are the purposes of dictionaries options2 and options3? (they don't appear to be used in the code?)

Comment: @Atlas7 they're not currently being used but they will be at some point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've got a lot of problems going on here unfortunately but I'll answer the specific question you asked:

'dict' is the name of the Dictionary data type in python so what you are attempting to do is use the type name instead of the variable. Kind of like asking str.index('a'). you've got to use a variable instead of the type.
replacing this:

```
if reply in dict.keys():
            print('true')
        else:
            print('false')
```

with this:

```
if reply in options1.keys():
            print('true')
        else:
            print('false')
```

does exactly what you want it to do. this creates and iterator of the dictionary's keys that the 'in' keyword uses to search through. if you try to do this on the base dictionary type, the interpreter will get confused and crash(when I tried to run it it just always returned false)

Also, as covered in the comments, you do this everywhere:

```
options1 = dict = {
```

This is unneccessary and dangerous. Having a variable name the same as a type(or keyword for that matter) is highly not recommended.

Comment: _Also, as covered in the comments, you do this everywhere:_
_options1 = dict = {_ haha yea. first time using dictionaries without the hand holding so i ended up fiddling with it at first. also cheers for the clarification for the 'dict.keys()' issue. must of taken the example i had way too literally :P

Comment: @Chris No worries man. To cover some other stuff in your code that causes concerns:
Your class syntax is confusing, I would put that code inside a function and not leave it open to execution interpretation. may cause problems if code gets more complicated.
Next time you post a question, do some testing to narrow down exactly where the problem lies. you could shove a string in for user input and cut out all of the printing, you also don't use 3 of the 4 dictionaries you specify in the question. SO can be unforgiving in booting unclear/low effort questions.
Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use options1 if you want to check for its keys, instead of dict

```
if str(reply) in options1.keys():    #checks to see if the number input by teh user is in the options1 dictionary.
    print('true')
else:
    print('false')
```

Comment: YES! thank you i hadn't even realised that i didn't specify which dictionary to search. cheers.

Comment: StackOverflow does not usually encourage naive questions - posted without testing thoroughly, but I understand your frustration. Accept my answer as it helped you.